# SQL Query to Calculate Values based on Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three relevant tables:

```
Evaluations:
EvalID
WorktypeID
PointsPossible

Items:
EvalID
ItemID
Value
QuestionID

Question_Worktype:
WorkTypeID
QuestionID
Points
```

There are multiple Items for each Evaluation, and each item has a QuestionID/WorkTypeID pair that relates to an entry in Question_Worktype, where the score lies.

Items.Value is whether an Item was correct or not.

I would like a query that returns the total Points of all Items for an Evaluation, Points only are awarded if the Value of the Item is 1.

My goal would be to get:

```
Eval_ID, Total Points (calculated), Points Possible
```

I can't seem to wrap my brain around it.

**Edit:** I forgot an important part:

I have an additional table:

```
qa_edits:
EditID
ItemID
NewValue
Date
```

If someone edits the value, it's stored here, and I really need it to calculate based on the newest edit for the item if there is one, or the item value if there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your edit table, to get the latest edit for each item:

```
SELECT
    M.ItemId,
    COALESCE(Q.Value, I.Value) as Value,
    I.QuestionId
FROM (
    SELECT
       I.ItemId,
       MAX(Date) as LastEditDate
    FROM Items as I
    LEFT OUTER JOIN QA_Edits as E ON
       I.ItemId = E.ItemId
    GROUP BY
       I.ItemId
) as M
LEFT OUTER JOIN QA_Edits as Q ON
    M.ItemId = Q.ItemId
    AND M.LastEditDate = Q.Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items as I ON 
    M.ItemId = Q.ItemId
    AND M.LastEditDate IS NULL
```

I'd suggest a view for that - let's call it `LatestItems`.

Then, back to [Blorgbeard's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106721/sql-query-to-calculate-values-based-on-conditions/5106772#5106772):

```
select
    e.Eval_ID, 
    sum(qw.Points) as TotalPoints, 
    e.PointsPossible
from Evaluations e
join LatestItems i on 
    e.Eval_ID = i.Eval_ID 
    and i.Value = 1
join Questions_WorkType qw on 
    qw.QuestionID = i.QuestionID
group by 
    e.Eval_ID, e.PointsPossible
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
select e.Eval_ID, sum(qw.Points) as TotalPoints, e.PointsPossible
   from Evaluations e
   left join Items i on e.Eval_ID = i.Eval_ID and i.Value = 1
   join Questions_WorkType qw on qw.QuestionID = i.QuestionID
   group by e.Eval_ID, e.PointsPossible
```

Comment: This got me almost all the way there (I still needed to add qwWorktype =e.worktype to the Questions_WorkType join).


Unfortunately, I forgot another part of the system (it's been that kind of day):  I have an additional table:

`qa_edits:
EditID
ItemID
NewValue
Date`

If someone edits the value, it's stored here, and I really need it to calculate based on the newest edit for the item if there is one, or the item value if there isn't.

Sorry for forgetting that.